# Cleanest way to return a tuple containing a particular element?

Tags: python, tuples

In python, if I have a tuple of tuples, like so:

```
((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz'))
```

what is the most efficient/clean/pythonic way to return the 0th element of a tuple containing a particular 1st element. I'm assuming it can be done as a simple one-liner.

In other words, how do I return 2 using 'bar'?

---

This is the clunky equivalent of what I'm looking for, in case it wasn't clear:

```
for tup in ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')):
    if tup[1] == 'bar':
        tup[0]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a list comprehension if you want all such values:

```
>>> lis = ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz'))
>>> [x[0] for x in lis if x[1]=='bar' ]
[2]
```

If you want only one value:

```
>>> next((x[0] for x in lis if x[1]=='bar'), None)
2
```

If you're doing this multiple times then convert that list of tuples into a dict:

```
>>> d = {v:k for k,v in ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz'))}
>>> d['bar']
2
>>> d['foo']
1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lis = ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz'))
>>> dict(map(reversed, lis))['bar']
2
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a "functional" way of doing it:

```
filter(lambda x: x[1]=='bar',((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz')))[0][0]
```

or borrowing from elazar because I like it so much:

```
dict(map(lambda x: (x[1],x[0]),((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz'))))['bar']
```

or indeed like elazar stated but in a oneliner:

```
dict(map(reversed,((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz'))))['bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = ((1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar'), (3, 'baz'))

try:
    value = [x[0] for x in t if x[1]=='bar'][0]
except IndexError:
    raise Exception('Does not exist')
```